# Server issue on MVC application - w3wp.exe running high

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-6, windows-server-2003

Got a mini-crisis on my hands here.  Running an MVC project on windows 2003, and the system is running really slow and producing errors - sometimes - when customers try to put through orders.

The errors seem to come in flurries, and when I've gone to check the server at the time that errors are coming through, the w3wp.exe process is sitting at around 99% CPU in the task manager.

Set up error emails to send details when the error is caught the only message I get is
Exception - Thread has been aborted
Source - MScorlib

I've added Elmah to the project to try and trace errors, but in typical style, I've had no errors in the hour since I added it!

Just wondered if anyone had come across this scenario before that could give me some options to try.  Any ideas would be great thanks

Comment: Ok, got an error message from Elmah, but it wasn't that much help.  'System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out' - it lists the action that the error happens on, but there is nothing that has changed in that section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to single-step through your code in Visual Studio to see if there is heavy I/O going on (lots of DB-intensive calls for instance), or maybe even an infinite loop.

Alternatively you may profile your app with, for instance, ANTS Performance Profiler (http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler), this will tell you which methods and lines take up the most CPU time.

Comment: Thanks for that Roy - I think you're right, that's probably the only option I have.